# How write *::selection{} in scss\sass?

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

I tried to do the following, but it does not work:

```
* {
    &::selection { text-decoration: underline; }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

That's the way I do it:

```
// define it
@mixin selection {
    ::-moz-selection { @content; }
    ::selection { @content; }
}

// use it
@include selection {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
```

## Update

I recommend to just use `::selection {}` with [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) instead of a mixin. This will make your code thinner and your brain lighter :)

In this case, [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) will transform this:

```
::selection {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
```

...(depending on your target browsers/configuration) into something like that:

```
::-moz-selection {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}

::selection {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely much cleaner and more reusable than Peter's answer. Hope it rises to the top!

Comment: @VitalyBatonov If your question is answered, mark it as it is :)

Comment: Sadly, I don't think that's going to happen - the OP hasn't been on the site since even before you posted this answer. Your answer has already risen to the top, however, so there's that at least.

Answer (score 11):

Mixins work with pseudo element selectors ;) see my mixin:

```
$prefixes: ("-moz-", "");
@mixin selection($color, $background) {
    @each $prefix in $prefixes {
        ::#{$prefix}selection {
            color: $color;
            background: $background;
        }
    }
}
```

how to use:

```
@include selection(white, black);
```

of course you can make it far more flexible, but it was sufficient for me ;)

Comment: ::selection has only a -moz prefix, and it's worth to note that it's a non standard and should not be used, check this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::selection) on Mozilla developer network.

Comment: @Peter: Strange that I missed it when I edited this answer the first time. I usually pay close attention to these things. (And yes, I know you're not the same Peter.)

Answer (score 7):

While the `::selection` pseudo-element was still in the [draft spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#UIfragments), `text-decoration` was not stated as one of the allowed style properties. Given that browsers implement it anyway, they should be following the rules according to that document, disallowing `text-decoration` as such.

That said, there's nothing wrong with your selector, although it's worth noting that Firefox uses the vendor-prefixed version `::-moz-selection` instead. You'd have to repeat the rule to support that browser, along with Chrome, Safari and Opera (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302172/firefox-moz-selection-selector-bug-is-there-a-workaround/5302221#5302221) for info).

So in SCSS, you'd do this:

```
* {
    &::-moz-selection { /* Style any selection */ }
    &::selection { /* Style any selection */ }
}
```

You might be able to reduce that using mixins, but I'm not sure if mixins work with pseudo-element selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Great mixin, I have changed to work inside a rule by adding "&", it works better for me. I have also added a empty prefix to get the rule with no prefix.

```
@mixin selection($color, $background) {
   $prefixes: ("-moz-", "-webkit-", "-o-", "-ms-", "");
   @each $prefix in $prefixes {
      &::#{$prefix}selection {
        color: $color;
        background: $background;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With compass you could do it like the following:

```
@import "compass/css3/selection";
@include selection($highlightBackground, $highlightColor)
```

Comment: "Just use someone else's library" does not explain how one would go about writing a similar feature that doesn't exist in said library.